# Stop ListView from populating all over again android

Tags: android, listview, fragment, state

I'm developing an app which has a ListView on a Fragment, I'm getting some data from SQLite using AsyncTask and filling a ListView, but every time i switch between the tabs, the ListView is populated all over again, it's not getting all the data again, but it is putting on the List again...

Is there a way to stop that? I want that my ListView is populated only once when i create the fragment, and when i swipe between the fragments it's be like when i hit the back button on my device, the list is there, and the items is already loaded

My current fragment OnCreateView

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

    lvTopRate = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.lv_top_rate);

    if(!isLoaded){
        new ManageSQLiteResponse(lvTopRate).execute();              
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

The ManageSQLiteResponse oonly is getting data from SQLite and executing updateList()

```
    public void updateList(ListView listView, ArrayList<DietBean> dietList){
    DietsListAdapter adapter = new DietsListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.single_top_rate, dietList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: How are you swiping between the Fragments? Are you sure they're not being destroyed and then recreated each time?

Comment: I'm using SlidingMenu library from jfeinstein10, on switching tabs its using:

 public void switchContent(Fragment fragment) {
  this.fragment = fragment;
  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
  getSlidingMenu().showContent();
 }

i'm sorry, i'm kind new to this